# Как увеличить значение dechex() php

Tags: php

Код:

```
echo $hex = dechex("10000000000000000000");
echo '<br>';
echo number_format(hexdec($hex), 0, '.', '');
```

Результат:

```
7fffffffffffffff
9223372036854775808
```

Вопрос: можно ли перевести число больше 9223372036854775808 в hex?

Comment: Просите у разработчиков процессоров больше разрядности чем 64 бита ;)

Comment: Давно уже пора переходить на 128 бит))

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать [свои функции конвертации](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.bc.php#99130) и работать со строками, а не с числами через функции для произвольной точности вычислений

```
<?php
function bchexdec($hex) {
    if(strlen($hex) == 1) {
        return hexdec($hex);
    } else {
        $remain = substr($hex, 0, -1);
        $last = substr($hex, -1);
        return bcadd(bcmul(16, bchexdec($remain)), hexdec($last));
    }
}

function bcdechex($dec) {
    $last = bcmod($dec, 16);
    $remain = bcdiv(bcsub($dec, $last), 16);

    if($remain == 0) {
        return dechex($last);
    } else {
        return bcdechex($remain).dechex($last);
    }
}

var_dump($hex = bcdechex("10000000000000000000"));
var_dump(bchexdec($hex));
```

[Результат](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f84f6a4e5d8d419b9e31fce84225b6202b94d07a):

```
string(16) "8AC7230489E80000"
string(20) "10000000000000000000"
```